# Override specific files in Grunt

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have three projects: Proj A which contains a basic setup with files to be reused in many different projects, non editable. And Proj B and C, which uses the files from Proj A as its base. Each project has its own Gruntfile.

I want to customize some JS and SCSS files in Proj B and C, (e.g change colours/variables). But know that Proj A might be updated every now and then, so I can't edit any of those basic files as they would be overwritten when pulling the latest changes into B and C. I therefore have to create customised files which should override the files from Proj A.

**1)**

A way of doing it could be to copy the file I want to edit and simply add 'override' to it's filename:

ui/styles/sass/**_override_colors.scss** *(should override ui/styles/sass/_colors.scss)*
ui/scripts/**_override_base.js** *(should override ui/scripts/base.js)*

The problem then is: how do I specify this rule in my Gruntfile, "if any file starting with '_override' exists, is should override its equivalent file".
That might however not be optional if the file I copy is large, as it means two quite identiacall large files.

**2)**

One other approach could be to add a new file called _overrides.scss and add it in the very end in my @import file. That however would be a bad idea if I am to change a lot of things, as it might be too messy and big and also means duplicate code (unless I am only overriding variables and no classes).

Which approach would you go for? Are there any other better ways to solve this problem?

Thanks!

```
web.scss:
@import 'colors';
@import 'grid';
@import 'base';
// @import 'overrides'; ?


grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded',
                sourcemap: true,
                quiet: true

            },
            files: {
                'styles/css/web.css':       'styles/sass/web.scss'
            }
        }
    },

    uglify: {
        site: {
            files: {
                'scripts/min/site.js': [
                    'scripts/dev/forms.js'
                    'scripts/dev/base.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    }, ....
```

Comment: For a simple solution i would go with option 1, using the copy task for example. Configure it to copy all `_override*` over, renaming them to the same without the `_override`. Although doing that properly will not be too easy.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think anything should happen at the `Gruntfile.js` level, as this concerns only `SASS`.

If you prefer the override way, name the override files as `_appB.scss` and `_appC.scss` and add them to the compilation. These files won't get bloated *as long as you only do overrides in them*.

You might however decide to go the non-override way and create dedicated selectors for each app - which takes some time getting used to but will prove more maintainable in the long run. That way every selector lives a life of its own.

### An override example:

**_appA.scss (common styles)**

```
.content { height: 80px; max-width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

**_appB.scss**

```
.content { height: 90px; }
```

**_appC.scss**

```
.content { height: 70px; max-width: 768px; }
```

**markup**

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

### A block/element/modifier "override" example:

**_appA.scss (common styles)**

```
.content { height: 80px; max-width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

**_appB.scss**

```
.content--b { height: 90px; }
```

**_appC.scss**

```
.content--c { height: 70px; max-width: 768px; }
```

**markup**

```
<div class="content content--b"></div>
<div class="content content--c"></div>
```

The last markup example above is a representation of [BEM syntax](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/), which is a popular take on [OOCSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/).

Me and my colleagues at work maintain complex products and find this workflow very manageable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It applies to both JS and SASS actually. Unfortunately the markup will be identical and completely inherited from Proj A, so adding modifiers and new classes won't be possible, even though I agree it would be the nicest way of solving it.

Comment: This does not address the problem and assumes facts explicitly contradicted in OP's question.